# Inserting Columns Without Duplicated Null Data in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

i don't know mysql very much. And i've problem about that. I've a database and it's 20 GB. I want to combine 4 columns and then move the combined column to the new one. But the problem is duplicated data in the table.

For example i wanna combine;

```
 Column1(Not Null), 
 Column2(Some of them null, some of them not null), 
 Column3(Not Null), 
 Column4(Some of them null, some of them not null).
```

And my new column, which i want to move my combined columns, is fully empty. After my longly research, at last i find this code on dev.mysql.com

```
  INSERT INTO my_table (new_content)
  SELECT Column1
  FROM my_table WHERE my_table > 0;
```

As a result, it moved Column1 to the new_content. But my the other 20 columns were duplicated too, as empty fields. How can i make it in an easy way?

Sorry for my bad English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what  do you mean for merge columns?

Comment: to combine @scaisEdge

Comment: you mean concat  the columns in a singol  column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the column in already existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN new_content VARCHAR(55);
```

Update table and concate all the columns to the newly created column:

```
UPDATE my_table SET new_content = CONCAT(Column1, Column2);
```

Create a trigger for all inserting values in future as well:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.new_content = CONCAT(Column1, Column2);
```

You can also create a trigger for UPDATE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.new_content = CONCAT(Column1, Column2);
```

Comment: Thanks but it works fifty fifty. Some rows' contents are full of combined contents but some are still empty. Why did it happen?

Comment: I found it. Triggers caused it. I solved the problem with your answer. Thanks a lot! @Jay Payel

Comment: I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a resulting column based on the string concatenation fo the column you can use concat

```
 INSERT INTO my_table (new_content)
 SELECT concat(Column1 , Column2, Column3, Column4)
 FROM my_table ;
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'Column1' in 'field list'